# Cohort Analysis in SQL - Total Returning Users for that Day regardless if the user had visited in the previous days

Tags: mysql, sql, retention

I have the following data (base_data):

```
visit_date  user_id
11/12/2021  Jake
11/12/2021  Amy
12/12/2021  Holt
12/12/2021  Jake
13/12/2021  Amy
13/12/2021  Jake
14/12/2021  Jake
14/12/2021  Holt
```

There are two users that visit on 11th and then only one of them visit on 12th. Hence where 11th is the first day, Day_1 = 2 and Day_2 = 1.

According to my query, I get the following result after pivoting rcohortday as row and day_number as column:

```
Date       Day_1    Day_2   Day_3   Day_4
11/12/2021     2        1       2       1
12/12/2021     1        0       1   
13/12/2021     0        0       
14/12/2021     1
```

However, the 12/12/2021 row doesn't consider the user that arrived on the 1st and the 2nd day. I want it to consider totals for that day regardless if the user had visited in the previous days or not.

My desired result would be:

```
Date       Day_1    Day_2   Day_3   Day_4
11/12/2021     2        1       2       1
12/12/2021     2        1       1   
13/12/2021     2        1       
14/12/2021     1
```

Let me know if you need anymore clarity especially with the examples.

The following is my query:

```
with user_cohorts as (
    SELECT  user_id
            , MIN(DATETRUNC(to_date(visit_date, 'yyyymmdd'),'dd')) as cohortday
    FROM base_data
    GROUP BY user_id
),

visit_day as (
    SELECT  user_id
            , (DATEDIFF(to_date(visit_date, 'yyyymmdd'),cohortday, 'dd')+1) as day_number
            , count(distinct user_id) as user_count
    FROM base_data
    LEFT JOIN user_cohorts USING(user_id)
    GROUP BY user_id, DATEDIFF(to_date(visit_date, 'yyyymmdd'),cohortday, 'dd')

),

cohort_size as (
    SELECT  count(*) as user_count
            , cohortday
    FROM user_cohorts
    GROUP BY cohortday 
    ORDER BY cohortday 
),

retention_table as (
    SELECT  c.cohortday as rcohortday
            , o.day_number
            , sum(user_count) as user_count
    FROM visit_day o
    LEFT JOIN user_cohorts c USING (user_id) 
    group by c.cohortday
            , o.day_number
)

select * from retention_table
```

I am using Max compute SQL which is an Ali Baba technology. It's similar to MySQL.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want.  It is not clear.  Why do the numbers go from 2/1/2/1 in the first row?

Comment: There are two users that visit on 11th (Jake, Amy) and then only one of them visits on 12th (Jake). Both of them visit on 13th again and only Jake visits on 14th, hence where 11th is the first day, Day_1 = 2, Day_2 = 1, Day_3 = 2, Day_4 = 1. Makes sense?